# WD TV Live + WD My Book + PS3 + HD TV + 5.1 receiver for them all?

Tags: ps3, audio-hardware

I intend to play some network content over the HD TV.
I would like to, as well, play some ps3 games, and benefit on both, from the same 5.1 sound system.

I'm not sure, how can I connect all this, or even if is possible for doing so.

Guessing:

I believe that WD TV Live does support HDMI out.
I believe the PS3 does support HDMI out.

Should I connect BOTH HDMI to the 5.1 receiver and from there, connect them to the TV ?

What about the visual part? I mean, If I connect the WD TV Live to the 5.1 receiver, I can't at the same time connect to the HD TV... Or, am I thinking wrong?

**Edited:** The 5.1 receiver could be, this one:
Sony Home Cinema HT-DDWG800

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to plug the PS3 and the WDLive to your receiver, both in HDMI as your receiver has three HDMI inputs, and connect the receiver HDMI output to your TV.
You'll then choose your source (WDLive or PS3) on the receiver and the TV will always stay on the same HDMI video channel.  HDMI carries both audio and video signals so there is no problem on this side, your receiver being a A/V one, it will carry the video part to your TV and take care of the sound output on the 6 speakers.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've updated my question with the 5.1 receiver that I intend to buy. I'm really not carring about branding here, the cheapest would do just fine because, regardless that, I believe we have a nice quality using such a configuration. Even if you don't know this particular model, where/what should we look on this and other models, in order to see if it fits or not? Thanks a lot again, MEM